# How do I round a double to 1 decimal place in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int cookiesPerClick;
    public int ClickUpgrade1Level = 0;
    public double cookies;
    public double ClickUpgrade1 = 50;
    public Text cookieText;
    public Text cookiePerClickText;
    public Text ClickUpgradeText;
    public Text ClickUpgradePriceText;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cookies = 0;
        cookiesPerClick = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        cookieText.text = "Cookies: " + cookies;
        cookiePerClickText.text = "Cookies Per Click: " + cookiesPerClick;
        ClickUpgradeText.text = "Level: " + ClickUpgrade1Level;
        ClickUpgradePriceText.text = "Price: " + ClickUpgrade1;
    }

    public void MakeCookie()
    {
        cookies += cookiesPerClick;
    }

    public void ClickUpgradeOne()
    {
        if (cookies >= ClickUpgrade1)
        {
            cookiesPerClick += 1;
            cookies -= ClickUpgrade1;
            ClickUpgrade1 *= 1.17;
            ClickUpgrade1Level += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Poor!");
        }
    }
}
```

After a few upgrades of ClickUpgrade1 it would start to things like this:
[Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNYPt.png)

It also does the same for the upgrade price and was just wondering how to round it down to make it more cleaner, thank you in advance.

Comment: [Math.Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-5.0) not working for you? if so, could you please elaborate why?

Comment: Fail safe that works in any language: *10, round, /10

Answer (score 0):

Format the double to a string using the F1 specifier:

```
cookieText.text = "Cookies: " + cookies.ToString("F1");
```